# WP_Query и другие записи из категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Хочу сделать после поста другие записи из этой же категории. Но есть еще один нюанс, создал произвольное поле и там указываю ID, которые хочу чтобы к нему выводились. Дальше использую WP_Query

```
$id = get_the_id();
$categories = get_the_category($id);

$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'category__in' => $cats_id,
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts__not_in' => array($id)
        );
// Проверяю полученныя данные из проивольного поля
if($related_to_this_post) {
        $args['post__in'] = $related_to_this_post;
    }
```

Так вот проблема в том, что если в произвольном поле я укажу только один id (заносятся в переменную $related_to_this_post), то и выводится один, а хотелось бы чтобы остальные ID вывелись рандомно.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы выводилось все равно 4 поста?

Comment: Надо делать 2 запроса. Первый - по posts__in, второй по рандомным постам, в количестве 4 минус кол-во в related. Потом результаты двух запросов объединять и выводить полученные 4 поста. Другого способа не вижу.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, обьединить их на этапе создания массива аргументов? До создания нового обьекта WP_Query?

Comment: Нет. Делаете первый запрос, сохраняете результат. Потом второй